# When I scale down the page, the box for the class "rcorners2" goes off the page at some parts. How do I fix this so it scales down smoothly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-grid, box-sizing

The expected result is for the box to scale 
down and fit into the center of the page 
without going off the side of the page. 
However, the actual result is that it goes off 
the side of the page when I scale down to some 
sizes. I don't really want to add in another 
screen size because I feel that the ones I have 
already should be adequate. Can anyone help 
with a solution for this issue, thanks.

```
html:

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device- 
width, 
initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Student Hacks</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
<link rel="icon" href="img/pencil.png">
</head>
<body class="grid">

<header>
  <img class="logo" href="index.html" src="img/student-hacks-logo.png" alt="Logo">
</header>

<div class="menu" id="menu-toggle"></div>
<nav id="menu-nav">
  <a class="home" href="index.html">HOME</a>
  <a class="money" href="money.html">MONEY</a>
  <a class="study" href="study.html">STUDY</a>
  <a class="faqs" href="faqs.html">FAQs</a>
</nav>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="img/moneysaving.jpg" alt="image of money">
    <div class="text">Money Tips & Tricks</div>
  </div>

  <div class="animation"></div>

  <h2 class="heading">Ways To Save Money</h2>

  <hr class="index-hr-1">

  <h3>Evening Shopping!</h3>
  <p class="rcorners2">Shop in the evenings, this way
    there will be a lot more discounted items. There are
    sometimes dedicated shopping isles for discounted
    items.</p>

  <h3>Student Discounts!</h3>
  <p class="rcorners2">UniDays and NUS are great ways
    to save money. They provide student discount cards
    that are compatible with many stores and restaurants.</p>

  <h3>Travel Cards!</h3>
  <p class="rcorners2">Purchase a 16-25 railcard to travel for
    discounted prices. If you have a 123 Student Bank Account
    with santander, you get the card for free!</p>

  <h3>Budget, Budget, Budget!</h3>
  <p class="rcorners2">When you receive your student loan,
    start budgeting it out on essentials. Budget food, books,
    rent,bills, etc. This lets you know where all your money
    is going.</p>
</main>

<footer class="footer">
  <p class="footer-writing">Student Hacks© 2018</p>
</footer>

<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

css:

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, 
monospace;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: black;
}
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
  "header"
  "menu"
  "content"
  "footer";
}
header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: #e5e5e5;
  height: 100px;
} 
.logo {
  width: 350px;
  height: 90px;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
nav {
  grid-area: menu;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
nav a {
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  background: #bfbfbf;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #dfd;
  background: #7d8687;
}
.home {
  height: 3vh;
}
.money {
  height: 3vh;
}
.study {
  height: 3vh;
}
.faqs {
  height: 3vh;
}
main {
  grid-area: content;
  /* increasing the height of one element increases all row heights */
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
.text {
  color: #94FCDD;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 2px #000;
}
footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #CDCDCD;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
}
.footer-writing {
  text-align: center;
}
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  text-align: center;
}
.heading {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
.faq-hr-1 {
  /* border: dashed 1.5px;
  width: 35%;
  margin-bottom: 75px;
  margin-top: 35px; */
  height: 10px;
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px -10px #8c8b8b inset;
}
.index-hr-1 {
  height: 10px;
  border: 0;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 12px 12px -10px #8c8b8b inset;
}
.about-us-text {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-right: 25px;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: table;
  width: 90%;
  border-spacing: 0 10px;
}

li {
  display: table-row;
}

li strong, li .txt, li .langs {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img {
  display: table-cell;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

li .txt {
  width: 60%;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #eee;
}
.wiki-label {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
.submit-btn {
  margin-left: 2%;
}
.rcorners2 {
  border-radius: 35px;
  border: 5px solid #94FCDD;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 40%;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 115px;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {

/* applies to screens wider than 499px */

body {
  background: #e5e5e5;
}

.grid {
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
/*grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;*/
/*or set the rows to 'view height (vh)'*/
grid-template-areas:
  "header  header  header"
  "menu    menu    menu"
  "content content content"
  "footer  footer  footer";
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #dfd;
  background: #7d8687;
}
.logo {
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.text {
  color: #94FCDD;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 45%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 2px #000;
}
header {
  height: 150px;
}
.rcorners2 {
  border-radius: 35px;
  border: 5px solid #94FCDD;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 20%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 145px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* DESKTOP STYLES */

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {

/* applies to screens wider than 999px */

body {
  background: white;
}
.grid {
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
/*grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;*/
/*or set the rows to 'view height (vh)'*/
grid-template-areas:
  "header  header  header"
  "menu    menu    menu"
  "content content content"
  "footer  footer  footer";
}

.rcorners2 {
  border-radius: 35px;
  border: 5px solid #94FCDD;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 20%;
  margin-right: 40%;
  width: 800px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
.text {
  color: #94FCDD;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 52%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 4px 2px 2px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using media queries, this is great. However you have a typo. You opened the media queries but never closed them.

example:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
body {
background: white;
}
 **}**
```

don't forget to close your media queries.

Also inspect in the browser where these errors are happening and you could always add more Media queries to remedy the situation. good luck!